# “Unable to obtain result of 'adb version' ”というエラーが出る

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipseに[Andmore](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore)のADTをインストールして使おうとしています。Eclipseを起動しようとすると、次のようなエラーが出ます。

> Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'

このエラーで困ったことはまだ無いのですが、このエラーを改善したいと思っています。

どうすればこのエラーを改善できるでしょうか。

マルチポスト: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41076463/6366398)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andmoreは使用したことがありませんが、おそらくadbにPATHが通っていないんでしょう。
シェルでadb versionを入力してみてください、同じエラーが出ると思います。
adbにPATHを通す方法は、実行環境にもよるので現段階だとわかりませんが、
「<自分の使用しているOS> adb PATH」などと調べてみれば分かるんじゃないですかね。（たとえばMacで開発しているのなら「mac adb PATH」など）

Comment: 環境変数の追加を忘れていました... ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

## Windows

Windowsのバージョンによって方法が違います。

### Windows10

1. Administratorとしてログイン。
2. 左下のWindowsのアイコンを右クリックし、システムをクリック。(システムのプロパティ)
3. 左側にある「システムの詳細設定」をクリック
4. 環境変数と書かれたボタンをクリック
5. システム環境変数の変数名がPathの変数をクリックし、編集と書かれたボタンをクリック
6. 「新規」と書かれたボタンをクリックし、platform-toolsのパスを入力。誤字がないのを確認し、Okをクリック。

### Windows7

1. Administratorとしてログイン
2. スタートをクリックし、コンピューターを右クリックしてプロパティを開き、システムの詳細設定を開く
3. 環境変数と書かれたボタンをクリック。
4. システム環境変数にある変数名Pathの行をクリックし、編集ボタンをクリック。
5. 変数値にplatform-toolsのパスを追加。入力されているものは消さない。
6. Okボタンをクリックし、すべてのダイアログを閉じる。

Answer (score 0):

## Linux

1. `Shell`にこのコマンドを入力しディレクトリを移動する。

```
cd ~/
```

2. viコマンドを使って`.bashrc`というファイルを編集する。

```
vi .bashrc
```

3. ↓キーでファイルの一番下まで降り、oキーを入力し空行を入れる。
4. 以下を入力:

```
JAVA_HOME=~/jdk(バージョン)    
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME PATH
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=~/android-sdk
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/tools
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME PATH
```

5. ESCを押し、`:w`と入力すると保存ができる。`:q`と入力するとviを終了できる。

Answer (score 0):

Avastなどを使用している場合はファイアウォールの設定を確認する必要があるみたいです。
Avastでの設定方法は以下の通りです。

1. Avastを開き、設定をクリックします。
2. 左のタブにある、"コンポーネント"をクリックします。
3. "ファイルシステムシールド"にある"カスタマイズ"をクリックします。
4. "スキャンからの除外"をクリックし、Android SDK、Android Studioのパスを例外に登録します。